# Javascript filter/find function is rounding numbers

Tags: javascript, filter, find, rounding

I am new to JS, I am working on a map application, I have to filter a geoJson file, using the filter or find function, the value of the coordinates is rounded, Im getting -8248331.906734363 instead of -8248331.906734363**175929**

Is there some way to get the correct value?

```js
const Floor1 = {
points:{
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "name": "PointsP2",
      "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
      "features": [
      { "type": "Feature", 
        "properties": { "id": null, "type": "point", "name": "rehab" }, 
        "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -8248331.906734363175929, 518109.842791541363113 ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", 
        "properties": { "id": null, "type": "point", "name": "fisio" }, 
        "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -8248323.718446247279644, 518115.804757916892413 ] } 
      }]
  }
}  
const findRoomByName = name => {
  let found = Floor1.points.features.filter( //find
    feature => feature.properties.name.indexOf(name) > -1);
  return found ;
}
console.log(findRoomByName("fisio"))
```

the result if i search '`rehab`' is:

```
... 
properties: Object
geometry: Object
type: "Point"
coordinates: Array(2)
    0: -8248331.906734363
    1: 518109.84279154136
...
```

Comment: In Chrome I get `-8248331.906734363175928592681884765625` if I do a toFixed(30)

Comment: I made you a working snippet.